# Can I work directly with spatial (PostGIS/SDE) DB with SQL queries?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, postgis, enterprise-geodatabase

There is some instruments like ArcPy for working with spatial DB. But can I do same work with simple (for example) PostgeSQL driver for Python?

Can I do select data column from DB A and insert data to DB B (only specified tables that include my feature class)? I have heard that PostGIS/SDE add some tables and if I will do it without touching PostGIS/SDE tables (that possible store some of indexes for my data) I will damage my data.

Comment: This list of things you can or can't do is highly dependent on how the tables have been created and configured.  The list is long and complex. Suffice it to say that "I've Heard" isn't the most reliable informant on this topic.

Comment: Vince, where I can read about it more?

Comment: I've spent the past nine months using PostgreSQL extensively, both in an enterprise geodatabase and without one. There have been a few things I *should* have been able to do (for which I needed a QFE), but for the most part I've done whatever I needed to, using both `arcpy` and SQL interchangeably. There are thousands of pages of documentation for ArcGIS with respect to enterprise geodatabases. I would suggest you start with the basics of user/schema requirements, then experiment . You can ask a different question if you get stuck (but you'll need to provide extensive *details*).